# assistance in numpy savetext format creates an error

Tags: python, numpy

I have to export camera distance to a txt/data file.
when im working in im having an error.

any idea how to overcome it.

Not entire code is posted

```
perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)

g = float("{0:.2f}".format(perimeter))

timestamped_camera_readings = np.append(timestamped_sensor_readings, (((154*58)/(g/4))*0.2645 ))

with open("camera_diatance.txt", "ab") as f:
    np.savetxt(f, np.expand_dims(timestamped_camera_readings, axis=0),  fmt=write_fmt)
```

#### saving it to a file

```
Error raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/merger/merger.py", line 118, in <module>
np.savetxt(f, np.expand_dims(timestamped_camera_readings, 
axis=0),fmt=write_fmt)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1196, in
```

savetxt
    raise error
     ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %4.2f %4.2f %4.2f %4.2f 
    %4.2f %4.2f %4.2f %4.2f %.0f

Comment: Hello, which row is throwing the error ? Can you please post the full trace of the error you get ?

Comment: What is the value of `write_fmt`? Your error is coming from there.

Comment: @reportgunner 
the row throwing error is 
np.savetext.........

Comment: @saran see comment from Alec

Comment: The number of columns in the array you are writing has to match the number of `%` formats in the `fmt`.  Basically what `savetxt` does is iterate on the rows of the array, and write `fmt % tuple(row)` to the file.  When you provide a simple `fmt`, it replicates it match the number of columns in the first row.  But it uses the complicate `fmt` as is.